# jQuery class descendant not accessed as planned

Tags: jquery, css

I'm building a photo gallery and need to apply some CSS to the first photo within view of my #wrapper div. Here's the relevant code:

```
$('.inside:first-of-type>div:nth-of-type(1)').css('display', 'none');
$('.inside:first-of-type>div:nth-of-type(2)').css('display', 'block');
```

All elements within view of the #wrapper div are assigned the class .inside (this class is removed once they slide outside #wrapper). Each photo has two div layers. In this instance, I want to hide the 1st and remove the 2nd layer. I thought the above code would work, and it does, but only if the first photo of the series is in view, otherwise it does nothing.

Is my CSS wrong here?

Comment: I don't think 'of-type' is valid.  You would do .inside:first and then do div:nth-child(1) and div:nth-child(2)

Comment: @DanielLorenz. You're right, there is not! if you want the type, you just write the type...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, there is no such selector: `first-of-type` in `jQuery`, and so in most of the browers.

This is what you need:

```
var items = $('#wrapper .inside > div');
items.eq(0).css('display', 'none');
items.eq(1).css('display', 'block');
```

Notes:

- You better cache the selector result, and avoid the second DOM query.
- You can use the `hide` function on the first div: `items.eq(0).hide();`
- `I want to hide the 1st and remove the 2nd layer.`
  `.css('display', 'block');` doesn't remove anything! You probably want to use the `remove` function: `items.eq(1).remove();`

Comment: @MarcinJuraszek. Who said jQuery support it? there is no such thing in the API! If you want to select the "first of type" you just write `$('{type-like div:first}')` Please check jQuery doc before you down-vote!

Comment: Right, my bad, there is no jQuery support for that, but that selector exists in general :) Just missed the jQuery context.

Comment: Typo on my part, I meant hide the first and display the second. Your method works for what I need so thank you. I guess my confusion came from assuming that all CSS3 selectors were supported by jQuery. :)